# Where can we download a curated dataframe of the full archive of UniProt?

Tags: uniprot

I want to download a curated dataframe of the full archive of UniProt.

Any format as long as it is a table (`.csv`, `.tsv`, `SQL` etc.).

Solution 1: Download the .fasta and do the formating myself -> very slow + information incomplete.

Solution 2: Use API like [BioServices](https://github.com/cokelaer/bioservices) -> still very slow but more information.

Do we have an already-curated dataframe containing as complete as possible the entry + metadata of UniProt that can be downloaded right away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answer from @matteo-ferla, converted from comment:*

There are many tables in the downloads page such tables enumerating each protein in a species proteome with basic stats, but not all the data. The uniprot records are very structured so would convert poorly to a table (even filling cells with lists/arrays and dictionaries/objects)… so a fuller table would be a mess.